# A-Records, NS-Records and MX-Records in DNS and Domain management

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I have a domain with godaddy, shared hosting with discountasp.net and email with google apps. I have no idea what to do with the name server discountasp.net gave me. Where do I put them? In A-Records or NS-Records?

In this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/88154/dns-ns-records-vs-a-record/88155#88155), I see that if I hand over the NS to discountasp.net, then I will loose control to my MX-Records (I hope I understood this wrong).

This is what my NS-Record on godaddy looks like after I added the ones discountasp.net gave to me:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discountasp.net wants you to delegate your domain to them, I would assume they have a control panel to manage your DNS much like godaddy but you would need to check first. If they don't you would loose the ability to edit your zone file, include the MX records.

If your domain zone has been created at discountasp.net, which is normally done automatically when you sign up to a hosting provider, you can query their DNS for the records you want (A, www etc) and add them in at godaddy to achieve the same thing.

eg:

```
dig A +short yourdomain @ns1.discountasp.net
dig A +short www.yourdomain @ns1.discountasp.net

[user@query ~]$ dig A +short www.vps4ever.com @ns1.instradns.com
119.252.176.36
```

So you would create an A record with the host of www and the content of 119.252.176.36 in the godaddy control panel.

EDIT: As per your picture you DO NOT want to add two sets of name servers. Choose either the godaddy ones or the discountasp.net ones.

Comment: I found this editor on discountasp.net. I changed the whole thing over to discountasp dns. A follow up question for MX. They require a subdomain for each MX address google gives. Do I leave it blank?

Comment: You leave the host blank (some require a @ symbol) and enter in the MX address from google in the content field. if you are using google apps assign a low priority (10) to the record aspmx.l.google.com. The other records can have the same priority (20) as these are back up servers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide what nameserver you use. You can use any name server you want. The thing is that all of your record should be under that name server. You can have your mail hosted with google, web hosted with discountasp.net however all of your records (NS,MX,A,PTR...) should be under one name server. You will give that name server to your domain registrar (godady). You can use godady Name Server (if they have) or use the one your shared hosting provides. Again important thing is all of your records should be hosted in one name server.

Comment: I edited my question and added an image. There are 2 non-editable name servers there. Am I correct in adding the 3 from discountasp.net there?

Comment: Yes, you did right. Basically what you did was pointing your hosting name server as your dns record authority. Now you need to create your dns records on your hosting name server. I believe they should even have some documentation for how to create dns records if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: shawn, lastly you don't have to use your hosting name server if godady already provides one for you. Just use go dady don't make things complicated for you

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**1 - Host all of your name records with Godaddy**

You will need to add the records that Discountasp.net wants you to have, to the list of records currently at Godaddy. These will probably be A records for www. and @ (i.e. no 'www.' prefix). These A records will store the IP address of the webserver provided by Discoutasp.net for your service. Note that if the Discountasp.net webserver IP address changes, you will need to update the Godaddy record manually, as obviously Discountasp.net can only make this change if you choose to...

**2 - Host all of your name records with Discoutasp.net**

You will need to tell Godaddy that Discountasp.net is hosting the name records. This is different to adding regular A, MX etc. records at Godaddy. Before you delegate Discoutasp.net as hosting your records however, you will want to bring all of your Godaddy records (Mostly your MX records for Google Mail) across to Discoutasp.net (If they support custom records)

Hopefully this clarifies the architecture a bit :)