# How To Setup Website Nameservers Using Ubuntu 11.04 & Nginx on Amazon's EC2 Cloud?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, nginx, amazon-ec2, nameserver

I have nginx installed and showing a default page on Ubuntu 11.04 inside Amazon EC2.

How does one go about setting up multiple nameservers for a website and hosting it through amazon EC2?

I am already using EBS images and taking snapshots every so often...

I really just need help setting up and registering nameservers with nginx and Amazon's EC2 service.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense unless you mean 'name-based virtual hosts', instead of nameservers. A nameservers is another name for a DNS-server, but name-based virtual hosting is a technique to run multiple websites on a single webserver. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NGINX is a webserver (not DNS).

I recommend you avoid setting up your own DNS Servers and instead use a Service like Amazon's [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/12/06/announcing-amazon-route-53-dns-service/) or [Zerigo](http://zerigo.com). This will save you time so you can focus on problems that are not easily solved with a few dollars a month.

If you want to run your own DNS Server have a look at [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/23744/hosting-your-own-dns)

**EDIT:** 
In re-reading your question. I think you may be asking how to host multiple websites in NGiNX from the same server, if that is your question, use [VirtualHosts](http://wiki.nginx.org/VirtualHostExample). [Heres a good tutorial](http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/5/16/ubuntu-hardy-nginx-virtual-hosts/) for ubuntu. After setting up the virtual hosts, you will need to add the domain and records to the DNS Service provider of your choice, and point your domain to those nameservers from your domain registrar (Godaddy, eNom, etc.)

Also please avoid cross posting to multiple StackExchange sites:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450601/how-to-setup-website-nameservers-using-ubuntu-11-04-nginx-on-amazons-ec2-cloud)

Comment: I am really just trying to host one website from an amazon ec2 instance - not multiple websites. I was under the impression that nginx was a DNS as well but now that I know it's not I will find my answer much quicker, so thank you! P.S. I only cross posted about 12 hours later once I realized that I had posted in the wrong website, sorry! :S

Comment: no need to be sorry and it was not my intention to be rude :) NGiNX is great and very fast, we are using it in production to host quite a few wordpress installs. Checkout the slicehost articles they are a great starting point! http://articles.slicehost.com Cheers