# Create nameservers in Ubuntu server to host domains

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, bind, web-hosting, ubuntu-14.10

I have a domain(from IndiaLinks) and a VPS server(from OVH with an IP). Consider the domain as `mysite.com`. Before purchasing this vps, I used to host it with shared hosting by adding the given nameservers under the delegation. But here I don't have nameservers.

I have installed `Ubuntu 14.10` server, `apache2`, `php5` and `mysql` in my VPS. I am facing many challenges here.

- Can I use same domain as nameservers(`ns1.mysite.com`, `ns2.mysite.com` for `mysite.com`)?

So how to create the nameservers `ns1.mysite.com` and `ns2.mysite.com` in my VPS?

(Here I have few reference links but I am confused to use it based on my IP ) [Reference 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330148/how-do-i-do-a-complete-bind9-dns-server-configuration-with-a-hostname) and [Reference 2](http://docs.ovh.ca/en/guides-dns-configuration.html#using-your-own-dns-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need are called glue records: [What is a glue record?](https://serverfault.com/questions/309622/what-is-a-glue-record)

Essentially, without a glue record, your nameserver definition would be calling itself recursively; i.e., to resolve, ns1.mysite.com, first you have to resolve mysite.com, one step up.

Comment: Any step by step command idea to proceed? I am a pretty beginner.

Comment: @devo They're defined within your registrar's control panel. If you're looking for a step by step guide, I'm going to have to recommend that you [do not host your own DNS](http://serverfault.com/questions/23744/should-we-host-our-own-nameservers). Authoritative DNS is too dangerous of a topic to begin your learning with because it risks instability of your domain.

Comment: Thanks..it works! other step by step reference links http://www.servermom.org/how-to-add-new-site-into-your-apache-based-ubuntu-server/272/ and http://www.servermom.org/how-to-install-and-setup-bind9-on-ubuntu-server/136/