# DNS is not pointing

Tags: domain-name-system, centos6, web-hosting, hostname, dns-hosting

Let me clear scenario first

1)I purchased static IP from network provider and his name server is `INPUDIIDNSPRPRD01.TATACOMMUNICATIONS.COM` and `INCHVSIDNSSEPRD01.TATACOMMUNICATIONS.COM`

2)Then I just forwarded port 53(DNS) traffic from leased IP address to my centos dedicated server on local IP .My local server **"name server"** is `ns1.xxx.co.in` and `ns2.xxx.co.in.`

I already fed my dedicated device name server to my domain provider is `ns1.xxx.co.in` and `ns2.xxx.co.in` (Is this correct setting?).

When I run `nslookup xxx.co.in xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` it says **`connection time out`**.

The question is which name server I need to fed into domain provider panel(INPUDIIDNSPRPRD01.TATACOMMUNICATIONS.COM or ns1.xxx.xo.in)?

Note:--
1)When i ping this domain from local wi-fi connection it still gives me old IP address
2)When ping out of the local network using my mobile on 3G connection it says connection time out.

Don't really know the issue is ...
No forum works working on it for last two days.

Feel free to ask for more info if needed to analyze the issue.

Comment: Some clarifications please. 1. Static IP addresses don't have nameservers. Domain names have nameservers. Are the nameservers you mention actually for the `xxx.co.in` domain you purchased? 2. You have configured a nameserver on your dedicated server. Is it authoritative for the domain `xxx.co.in` (i.e. do you have a zone containing information it, and only it, knows)? 3. Wouldn't it be easier to leave the two public nameservers as your nameservers rather than running your own?

Comment: 4. Where did then names `ns1.xxx.co.in` and `ns2.xxx.co.in` come from? Do they both map to the address of your dedicated server? 5. If your own nameserver is responsible for resolving DNS for `xxx.co.in`, does the upstream nameservers already know where `ns1.xxx.co.in` and `ns2.xxx.co.in` are? Did you give them the IP addresses, too? 6. Your domain provided should be given the name (IP address) or your domain's working nameserver - it sounds like that you would like that to be your dedicated server.

Comment: ns1 and ns2 come from my dedicated centos server i just configure there.if you want to know domain name so it's poc.co.in. and my ip is 115.118.115.167. webmin and other port working on ip address but it just can't resolve my domain name.Name server is authorised.

Comment: http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=whois&host=115.118.115.167 i find name server of ip.

Comment: We need to know the domain name in question.

Comment: domain name poc.co.in

Comment: Your link to network-tools.com does a whois lookup on the IP address. That's not a nameserver lookup.

Comment: Obligatory link: [Should we host our own nameservers?](http://serverfault.com/questions/23744/should-we-host-our-own-nameservers)

Answer (score 2):

Looking up the domain `poc.co.in` in the nameservers shows that it is registered with the `co.in` authority. It has two nameservers, `ns1.poc.co.in` and `ns1.poc.co.in`, both of which resolve to the same IP address `115.118.115.167`. (This is bad practice; for two nameservers you should have two different addresses.)

The nameserver on `115.118.115.167` is responding to TCP requests but not to the more usual UDP requests.

I would suggest that you need to adjust your firewall to permit inbound traffic for `udp/53` (as well as leaving `tcp/53` open) and it will all start working correctly.

Comment: UDP and TCP both the port is allowed to forward traffic to local ip address 192.168.1.163 and as i change name server also to point different ip address.

Comment: I still don't get a response on udp/53. I do get one for tcp/53. Please re-check your settings.