# Basic VPS and DNS / Nameserver questions

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, nameserver

I have this situation:

- my own domain `example.com` registered at **companyA.com**
- a cPanel/WHM hosting at **companyB.com**, where I have the website for `example.com`.
- a new VPS, provided by **companyC.com**

At **companyA.com**, I setup the Nameservers of `example.com` to point to `ns1.companyB.com` and `ns2.companyB.com`, and everything works.
Now I need to setup another website on the VPS, and make `sub.example.com` point to it.

This is my first VPS and I need some basic knowledge:

1) Do I need to change the hostname of the VPS? (currently `vpsXXX.companyC.com`)

2) Do I need to set the Nameservers on the VPS? To What? I don't want to run my own DNS.

3) At **companyB.com** I think I should insert an A record for `sub.example.com` pointing to the VPS IP, right?

The VPS has 1 IP Address, and runs CentOS 6 + CentOS Web Panel

Thank you very much

Comment: Vps ip u have, point your subdomain as an A record in company B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Do I need to change the hostname of the VPS?

A system can only have 1 hostname but many DNS names can be pointed towards it, but there is no technical requirement that favours one of those additional DNS records over the current hostname.

If you do change the hostname, just ensure that the reverse DNS records is updated accordingly.

> 2. Do I need to set the Nameservers on the VPS?

Normally you should [not need to run your own DNS **server**](https://serverfault.com/questions/23744/should-we-host-our-own-nameservers) to manage your domain(s).

But DNS resolving will need to *be configured* on the VPS so it can do DNS lookups. Typically the VPS will be deployed with correct settings in `/etc/resolv.conf` already but if not commonly used public DNS services are Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

> 3. At companyB.com I think I should insert an A record for sub.example.com. pointing to the VPS IP, right?

Yes! As simple as that.

Comment: Ok, I did point #3 and it works! 
Also, checked point #2, they are set to Google DNS, so ok.

#1 is still not so clear, though.. let's say I change the hostname to match my own domain.. what should I do to check the reverse DNS?

Thank you!

Comment: Reverse DNS is typically manager though Your hosting provider, check their management console and documentation. From the command prompt `dig -x <your IP address>` and also don't forget IPv6