# rDNS 'zone [xxx] has no address record (A or AAAA)

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, bind, reverse-dns

teaching myself some server tricks.

Getting trouble with bind9 on debian8.

```
named-checkzone pro.lan db.pro.lan.inv
zone pro.lan/IN: NS 'server.pro.lan' has no address records (A or AAAA)
```

my db.pro.lan.inv

```
    $TTL    604800
@    IN SOA server.pro.lan. root.pro.lan. (
    2015052402
    604800
    86400
    2419200
    604800
)

@ IN    NS    server.pro.lan.
254    IN PTR    server.pro.lan.
10    IN PTR    nas.pro.lan.
```

Any idea ?

Thks.

Answer (score 3):

Your `pro.lan` zone specifies a nameserver of `server.pro.lan`, but does not define that record. You need to add a `server IN A` record pointing at its IP address.

Additionally, your `pro.lan` zone is what is known as a "forward" zone - it maps names to IP addresses, not numbers to names. `PTR` records are used to map numbers to names, and therefore `PTR` records are functionally useless in this zone. I recommend picking up a book on DNS and reviewing the fundamentals.

Also, please review this question before you decide to start doing anything with DNS in your production environment: [Should we host our own nameservers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/23744/should-we-host-our-own-nameservers)

Answer (score 0):

Make a forward zone for `pro.lan` with an entry for `server.pro.lan.`  `NS` records always have to be names, and those names must be resolvable.  Apparently `server.pro.lan` is not resolvable currently.