# Can ping by IP address but not by hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, ping

I have 3 Debian VM. 1)DNS 2)DHCP 3)Client

DHCP looks ok. I got my fixed-address on DNS and Client like I want.

When I try to ping each of them @ip it's responding.
If I try to :

```
ping dhcp
```

But I got a :

```
unknown host dhcp
```

Same for nas.

I don't know where it come from because I have set my zone and db file correctly.

named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//
zone "pro.lan" {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/db.pro.lan";
};

zone "84.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/db.pro.lan.inv";
};


// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
```

db.pro.lan

```
$TTL 604800
@ IN SOA dns.pro.lan. root.pro.lan. (
  2015052401
  604800
  86400
  2419200
  604800
)

pro.lan IN NS   dns.pro.lan.

dns     IN A    192.168.84.50
dhcp    IN A    192.168.84.51
nas     IN A    192.168.84.10
```

db.pro.lan.inv

```
$TTL 604800
@ IN SOA dns.pro.lan. root.pro.lan. (
  2015052401
  604800
  86400
  2419200
  604800
)

IN      NS      dns.pro.lan.
50      IN PTR  dns
51      IN PTR  dhcp
10      IN PTR  nas
```

Edit : I modified the file thanks to @Eric Renouf

```
named-checkconf
```

it's looks good but

```
named-checkzone pro.lan db.pro.lan
zone pro.lan/IN: has no NS records
```

same for rDNS file.

Comment: You still have [one question open](http://serverfault.com/questions/694156/rdns-zone-xxx-has-no-address-record-a-or-aaaa) regarding the configuration of this zone file. Please make sure to click on the check box next to the answer that provided the solution that helped you so that the question does not show up in searches as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be with your `NS` record in db.pro.lan.  Your line starts with `pro.lan` which does not end in a `.` so will have the `pro.lan` automatically appended by `bind` so your domain there will become `pro.lan.pro.lan.` which isn't what you want.

If you just remove the `pro.lan` you should get what you want from that zone.  So your NS record will now look like:

```
    IN NS dns.pro.lan.
```

Make sure you increment the counter (`2015052401` in your case, should probably become `2015052501`) then do `rndc reload`

Comment: Thanks. I know the thing with the . at the end. I fixed for both files, incremented the serial and restart the service.

Unfortunately same problem.

Comment: I assume you're using your server for DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf`?  Just to eliminate the basic thing first

Comment: yes on each vm resolv.conf get set automatically with my DNS conf

Comment: @Ragnar I disagree; from the looks of your edit, you added trailing dots within your `SOA` record but did not touch your `NS` record. `pro.lan IN NS   dns.pro.lan.` translates to `pro.lan.pro.lan. IN NS   dns.pro.lan.`.

Comment: @Andrew B
Yes I had `@` instead and I read it act the same. It's working now thanks all

Comment: @Ragnar That was not reflected in your question or your edit. Your question as presented clearly has syntax problems and errors that correlate to them. :( It is getting very confusing to follow your questions and some of us are probably going to stop trying.

Answer (score 0):

When you run "`ping dhcp`" the library code that does name lookups looks for your local domain name in `/etc/resolv.conf` to append to "`dhcp`" to make `dhcp.pro.lan`

if "`ping dhcp.pro.lan`" works and "`ping dhcp`" does not then you need to add:

```
domain pro.lan
search pro.lan
```

to `/etc/resolv.conf`