# Is it possible to use a server simultaneously as name server for itself?

Tags: name

If I have only one server (domainxyz.com) can I use this server simultaneously as primary name server for this server?

domainxyz.com
ns1.domainxyz.com
ns2.otherdomain.com

I think this is a question whose correct answer very many people would like to know. Anytime I have read that many server owners do it like this.

Comment: `domainxyz.com` isn't a server, it's a domain.

Comment: Why don't you just use your registrar's name servers ?

Comment: @Iain Maybe search engines classify an own name server a sign of a more professional website

Comment: @user1941083: That's nonsense. Name servers don't contribute to search rankings and, in most cases, running your own NS is decidedly *not* professional anyway.

Comment: @user1941083 Perhaps but they would know what they are doing and not have to ask the question you did which basically indicated you are an amateur. If you want to run your own name servers (note the plural) then you should consult the relevant RFCs and be educated as to the breadth of your cluelessness.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/23744/should-we-host-our-own-nameservers

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's entirely possible. It's not necessarily a good idea though. Quite the opposite in most cases (as is running your own name servers in general, for small setups).