# Do ns1 & ns2 nameservers need a PTR record?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, reverse-dns

I wonder whether my 2 nameservers need a PTR record. As you may know the PTR record or reverse DNS is important for mail server hostname as it improves chances for your outgoing emails to be accepted by major email providers.

I also wonder if there are any cases where the PTR records (aka rDns) are checked against nameservers.

I have checked PTR records for the nameservers of big online companies and found that they all have a PTR record in place for all of their nameservers. (I think about the nameservers from Cloudflare, Cisco, Microsoft among others...). Note that i talk about nameservers and not about mail servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there is no requirement for nameservers to have `PTR` records. It's still a *very good idea* in order to make sure that these devices are well identified, but no functionality breaks if those records are missing.

That said, if you're having to ask this question, I think the more imminent issue is [whether or not](https://serverfault.com/questions/23744/should-we-host-our-own-nameservers) you should be running authoritative servers. They are very dangerous to the company when an admin is forced to learn through on the job experience. I say this as someone who has blown up a company domain in the distant past by trying to `CNAME` the apex. :)

Comment: +10 if I could for coming clean about CNAMEing the root (apex).  We have *all* made awful mistakes in the past, and if we own up to these, we can help more junior colleagues not to commit those particular errors (they will find their own disasters to perpetrate, and hopefully tell those on in their turn).