# How do I create a PTR record for my server?

Tags: domain-name-system, ptr-record

I assumed I would set up a PTR record with my other DNS records, but have been told by my hosting company that "a PTR record should be set up at the side of your server, not as a DNS record in your domain zone file." But I can't find any explanation, anywhere, for how to do this.

It's a Linux server.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that only your hosting provider can do. Maybe they offer this functionality in some kind of management menu, but this should be documented or their support should be able to walk you through the process. Ask them, we can't help you further.

Comment: I hope that was just a poor choice of words on their part, then. I'll ask again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A PTR record for a single IP address can be also delegated to your very own dns, so you could do it yourself. Usually this is done by ISPs.

It is also possible that your ISP has a web page to allow you to define it.

If neither case applies, then you will need to ask them to change the PTR record on your behalf. Your mileage may vary!

Anyway, if an IP address of yours is `1.2.3.4` and you have a DNS record A pointing to it like `www.mydomain.tld`, and **if your DNS server has been delegated for the reverse lookup**, the a minimal PTR record would look like this:

```
4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR www.mydomain.tld.
```

Be very careful with the **trailing dots**: the DNS won't forgive you!
We never use trailing dots, the DNS cannot leave without: it's part of the delegation tree.

Comment: Hi Enzo. I think the information here is useful, but you may get some reactionary downvotes due to prefacing your answer with a suggestion to manage your own DNS. The general consensus at Serverfault is that most people who choose to run their own DNS [do not know what they are getting themselves into](http://serverfault.com/questions/23744/should-we-host-our-own-nameservers), and that it is best left to professionals or well-known DNS hosting platforms. It's fine to mention the possibility, but your current phrasing comes across as overly encouraging. :)

Answer (score -2):

Take after strides to Create the PTR record

1. Scroll to the Bottom of the Zone proofreader and discover the area marked Add New Entries Below this Line.
2. In the main drop down menu, select PTR.
3. A box containing Hostname will show up. In the crate sort the space name you are adding the PTR record to. ...
4. Click the Save catch at the base.

Comment: This might be how it works at your provider. Others will be wildly different.

Answer (score -3):

A basic clarification of invert DNS is that it's the correct inverse of DNS. Standard (otherwise known as forward) DNS maps a space name to an IP address while invert DNS maps an IP deliver to an area name. The two are unmistakable and isolate queries in any case. Because a forward query of example.com sets out to 1.2.3.4 doesn't imply that a turn around query of 1.2.3.4 will take steps to example.com.