# How to setup own dns server

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-proxy

Suppose i have 3 Applications.
example1.com
example2.com
example3.com
all domains are in different registrar lets say  example1.com is in Godaddy, example2.com is in Bigrock and example3.com is in CrazyDomains.
My all this application are on different servers they all have dedicated ips also suppose.
Suppose app1 current ip is 1.1.1.1  ,app2 current ip is 2.2.2.2 ,app3 current ip is 3.3.3.3 app4 current ip is 4.4.4.4.

Lets say if i change servers of all above and now all above have different ips like
app1 11.11.11.11 ,app2 22.22.22.22 etc...
i have to update new ips to different domain registrar again with A record.
but what if i have something like my own 1 server which ip is permanent and lets say its 7.7.7.7 so i'll add this ip to all domains.

now this my new server will redirect to different hosts.

just like we manage DNS in Cpanel but in my case i don't want to update DNS to mine server i'll just update A records only. DNS will be by default managed by domain registrar.
Benefit will be for me is if i change if of my any app i dont have to update ip in domain registrar's DNS setting instead i'll directly update to my own server.

Comment: See [Should we host our own nameservers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/23744/should-we-host-our-own-nameservers).

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

If your apps use HTTP / TLS as the protocol, then you are describing a reverse proxy. Setting up a reverse proxy allows you to have one server that redirects traffic to different servers based on domain names.